# What is the maximum number of columns we can add to view in advanced datagrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to retrieve a table data into datagrid dynamically . But if the table contains more than 40 columns it overlaps my border container and data grid exceeds the container. It works fine as expected if the table is having less than 40 columns.

Comment: never been in this use case .  but if you switch to spark datagrid may be better (all rescent apache fixes are mainly focused on spark datagrid ) .

Answer (score 0):

Set the horizontalScrollPolicy:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
                     width="100%" height="100%"
                     horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" />
```